# filter list of list by matching with lists in other list regardless of their position

Tags: python

I have 2 lists of lists and I want to filter list1 based on matching with elements in list2:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,16]]
list2 = [[9,8,50], [7,10,3]]
```

the last element in each list is unique id (example list[0][-1] is unique)
I want to get the elements from list1 (list) that have the same last element in elements in list2

In my example

```
list1[0][-1] is similar to list2[1][-1]
```

I try this:

```
[x for x, y in zip(list1, list2) if x[-1] == y[-1]]
```

but it filter by position (check elements that have the same position in both lists)
I want to check them regardless of their position

**EDIT**
expected result:

```
[1,2,3] from the list 1 (because hit last element (list[-1]) is the same as  last element in a list inside list2)
```

Comment: Why don't you show us the expected result?

Comment: done, I added it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a `set` to first store all the ids from `list2`, and then filter `list1` using a list comprehension, like this:

```py
list2_ids = {x[-1] for x in list2}
result = [x for x in list1 if x[-1] in list2_ids]
```

Comment: When he said 'ids' I thought he meant the `id``of the object but I just realized he meant the last elements according to your answer

Comment: I meant unique id (can't be found elsewhere in other list inside list1)

Comment: @Adam.Er8 I can filter again the results by creating new list where matched elements in both lists has the same first element ?  because when I get the results, lists matched can differ at other positions

Answer (score -1):

```
list1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,16]]
list2 = [[9,8,50], [7,10,3]]

lst = [x for x in list1 if x[-1] in set([y[-1] for y in list2])]
#Out[3]: [[1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: So for every element in `list1`, you (re)compute a list of the ids from `list2` and on top of that even turn it into a set every time. Seems rather very inefficient and pointless.